# Calculate the level set of $(x^2+y^2)\log(1-z)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need help with the following question if possible. I'm not entirely sure on how I should begin.

Find the level set of $f$ which has value (“height”) $w_0 = 0$, and describe it in words and set notation. Confirm that the point $(2,2,0)$ is on this level surface, and that $\nabla f(2, 2, 0)$ is
perpendicular to this surface.

where $f = (x^2+y^2)\log(1-z)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply solve the equation
\begin{align}
\left( x^2 + y^2\right ) \ln (1-z) &= 0
\end{align}
Obviously, solution is 
\begin{align}
\left \{x, y, z \left |\ x = 0, y = 0, z \in (-\infty, 1) \right .  \right \} \cup \left \{x, y, z \left |\ x \in \mathbb R, y \in \mathbb R, z = 0 \right .  \right \}
\end{align}
In other words, zero level set is $z = 0$ plane with $z$-ray going from $1$ to infinity embedded to it.

Point $(2,2,0)$ is on that plane. Now find a gradient of the given function
\begin{align}
\nabla f = \left( 2x \ln (1-z), 2y \ln (1-z), -\frac {x^2+y^2}{1-z}\right )
\end{align}
so
\begin{align}
\left . \nabla f \right |_{(2,2,0)} = (0,0,-4)
\end{align}

The level set surface is a plane $z = 0$, and its normal is the vector along the $z$ axis, so is the $\left . \nabla f \right |_{(2,2,0)}$, therefore it's also normal to the plane.